# skip multiple headers with different format in txt file using ssis

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have received a txt file with multiple headers with 2 different formats and data is separated by pipe. I am using visual studio. I have to skip the headers while loading into target table.

**#Header1:sdate|actDate|Timzone|ID|SNO|EmpID|aID|Email|name|customerID|code|start|stop
#Header2:sdate,actDate,Timzone,ID,SNO,EmpID,aID,Email,name,customerID,code,start,stop**

28122022|28122022|USA|21561||12345|2|fatera.dash@gmail.com|fatera, dash|1|Break|22:45|23:00

In the above Header1 and header2 have to kipped and data should be load into target table.

I have given a try as skip headers 2 but it is not working.

Can anyone provide me a guidance on this.

Regards,
Khatija

Answer (score 0):

I have skipped by checking headers rows to skip as 3.